# How can I add button to WPF GridView

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

```
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:AraWPF"
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800">
    <Grid>
        <ListView x:Name="listView">
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="call" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Call}" Width="100" />
                    <GridViewColumn Header="name" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Name}" Width="200" />
                    <GridViewColumn Header="path" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path}" Width="100" />
                    <GridViewColumn Header="link" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Link}" Width="100" />
                    <GridViewColumn Header="description" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Description}" Width="100" />
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
        </ListView>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

it's my GridView to print my data
I want to add button to GridView.
Is there any way to add button to View which is table

I'm sorry for my bad english skill.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use templates:

```xml
<GridView>
    <GridViewColumn Header="call" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Call}" Width="100" />
    <GridViewColumn Header="name" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Name}" Width="200" />
    <GridViewColumn Header="path" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path}" Width="100" />
    <GridViewColumn Header="link" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Link}" Width="100" />
    <GridViewColumn Header="description" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Description}" Width="100" />
    <GridViewColumn Header="Button" Width="100">
        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <!-- Your button using bindings, ... -->
            </DataTemplate>
        </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
    </GridViewColumn>
</GridView>
```